# How to make this server output "Hey there!" after receiving a second port number as a message (java multithreaded socket)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

**Current results:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajhpb6biskqrp9i/Screen%20Shot%202017-10-26%20at%207.35.02%20PM.png?dl=0

**Notice:** In the screenshot above, the right window (client) message that says "Hey there!" does not appear on the left window (server) even though the message that says "Hey there!" was typed/executed first before "what's up" was typed/executed.

**Desired results:** 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtvfzgq85yqxn75/heythere.png?dl=0

Command line arguments to run **server**

```
java MessengerWithFiles -l 6001
```

Command line arguments to run **client**

```
java MessengerWithFiles -l 6002 -p 6001
```

The 6002 is the second port number which will be the message that is sent first (from the client to the server) This number will be needed in the future to transfer files.

**My question is:** What changes can I make to the following code that will produce the desired result screenshot? (this is a dynamic program, messages cannot be hard-coded)

The following code block is where the server receives the message, but appears to be blocking the first message "Hey there!". However, it is also supposed to receive the message "6002" before printing out "Hey there!" and store it in a string, (I used the split method to do this and replaceAll method to remove spaces in the string)

```
                    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String MessageFromClient = br.readLine();
                    String nullK = "null";
                    if(once == 4 && MessageFromClient.contains("fileport"))
                    {

                        String string = MessageFromClient;
                        String[] parts = string.split(":");
                        String part1 = parts[0]; 
                        String part2 = parts[1]; 
                        String k = parts[1].replaceAll("\\s+","");
                        filePort = Integer.parseInt(k); 
                        once = 7;

                    }
                    else if((MessageFromClient.contains(nullK) == true) ||MessageFromClient.equals(null) || MessageFromClient==null || MessageFromClient.equals("null") || MessageFromClient.equals(null))
                    {
                            is.close();
                            isr.close();
                            br.close();
                            socket.close();
                            System.exit(0);
                    }
                    else if (!MessageFromClient.equals("null") && !MessageFromClient.equals(null) && MessageFromClient !=null)
                    {
                        String nullS = "null";
                        if(MessageFromClient.contains(nullS) == false)
                        {
                          if(MessageFromClient!= "null")
                          {
                              if(MessageFromClient.equals("null") == false)
                              {
                                  if(MessageFromClient.contains("fileport"))
                                  {

                                      String string2 = MessageFromClient;
                                      String[] parts = string2.split(":");
                                      String part1 = parts[0]; 
                                      String part2 = parts[1]; 
                                  }
                                  else if(!MessageFromClient.contains("fileport"))
                                  {
                                      System.out.println(MessageFromClient);
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                        }
                    }
```

**Note:** If you already know the answer by this point, **SKIP** reading the rest of the code and scroll down to post an answer. Thanks.

Code of `MessengerClient.java`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class MessengerClient
{
    int once = 3;
    int ConnectOnce = 0;
    private String[] clientArgs; 
    private static Socket socket;
    public boolean keepRunning = true;
    public MessengerClient(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        if(args.length>2 && args.length!=2)
        {
            this.clientArgs = args;
            run(args);
        }
    }
    public String[] ClientRun(String[] args)
    {
        clientArgs = args;
        clientArgs = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);
        return clientArgs;
    }

    Thread ClientSend = new Thread();   
    public void run(String args[]) throws IOException
    {   
        while(keepRunning)
        {              

                if(ConnectOnce == 0 && args.length>2)
                {
                        String filePort = args[1];
                        String port_number1= args[3];
                        int port = Integer.valueOf(port_number1);
                        String host = "localhost";
                        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                        socket = new Socket(address, port);
                        ConnectOnce = 4;
                }
                try 
                {
                   OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                   OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                if(once == 3)
                {
                    bw.write("fileport is:" + args[1] + "\n");
                    once = 8;
                }
                once = 8;
                BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String line = input.readLine();

                     if(line !=null && !line.equals(null) && line!="null" && !line.equals("null"))
                     {

                         bw.write(line);
                         bw.newLine();
                         bw.flush();
                         runClientRead(clientArgs);
                     }
                     else if(line.equals("null") || line==null || line.equals(null))
                     {

                         os.close();
                         osw.close();
                         bw.close();
                         socket.close();
                         System.exit(0);
                     } 
                } 
                 catch (NullPointerException ignored)
                {
                         System.exit(0);
                }
                 catch (IOException e)
                 {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                 } 

             finally
             {  
             }  
        }
    }
    Thread ClientRead = new Thread();
    public void runClientRead(String args[]) throws IOException
    {   
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String MessageFromServer = br.readLine();
            String nullS = "null";
            if(MessageFromServer.equals(null) || MessageFromServer==null || MessageFromServer.equals("null"))
            {
                is.close();
                isr.close();
                br.close();
                socket.close();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if (!MessageFromServer.equals("null") && !MessageFromServer.equals(null) && MessageFromServer !=null)
            {
                if(MessageFromServer.contains(nullS) == false)
                {
                  if(MessageFromServer!= "null")
                  {
                      if(MessageFromServer.equals("null") == false)
                      {
                          if(!MessageFromServer.contains("Port"))
                          {
                              System.out.println(MessageFromServer);
                          }

                      }
                  }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Code of `MessengerServer.java`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MessengerServer 
{
        int filePort = 0;
        int once = 4;
        int ConnectOnce = 0;
        private static Socket socket;
        boolean KeepRunning = true;
        private String[] serverArgs; 
        public MessengerServer(String[] args) 
        {
            this.serverArgs = args;
        }
        void ServerRun(String[] args)
        {
            Thread Server = new Thread () 
            {
                public void run ()
                {   
                    try
                    {
                        if(ConnectOnce == 0)
                        {
                                int port_number1= Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
                                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                                socket = serverSocket.accept();    
                                ConnectOnce = 1;
                        }
                        while(KeepRunning) 
                        {
                            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                            String MessageFromClient = br.readLine();
                            String nullK = "null";
                            if(once == 4 && MessageFromClient.contains("fileport"))
                            {
                                String string = MessageFromClient;
                                String[] parts = string.split(":");
                                String part1 = parts[0]; 
                                String part2 = parts[1]; 
                                String k = parts[1].replaceAll("\\s+","");
                                filePort = Integer.parseInt(k); 
                                once = 7;
                            }
                            else if((MessageFromClient.contains(nullK) == true) ||MessageFromClient.equals(null) || MessageFromClient==null || MessageFromClient.equals("null") || MessageFromClient.equals(null))
                            {
                                is.close();
                                isr.close();
                                br.close();
                                socket.close();
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                            else if (!MessageFromClient.equals("null") && !MessageFromClient.equals(null) && MessageFromClient !=null)
                            {
                                String nullS = "null";
                                if(MessageFromClient.contains(nullS) == false)
                                {
                                    if(MessageFromClient!= "null")
                                    {
                                        if(MessageFromClient.equals("null") == false)
                                        {   
                                            if(MessageFromClient.contains("fileport"))
                                            {
                                                String string2 = MessageFromClient;
                                                String[] parts = string2.split(":");
                                                String part1 = parts[0]; 
                                                String part2 = parts[1]; 
                                                MessageFromClient = "";
                                            }
                                            else if(!MessageFromClient.contains("fileport"))
                                            {
                                                System.out.println(MessageFromClient);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                            BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                            String line = "";
                            line= input.readLine(); 
                            if( line != null && !line.equals(null) && line!="null" && !line.equals("null"))
                            {
                                bw.write(line);
                                bw.newLine();
                            }
                            else if(line=="null" ||  line.equals("null") || line.equals(null))
                            {
                                bw.flush();
                                os.close();
                                osw.close();
                                bw.close();
                                is.close();
                                isr.close();
                                br.close();
                                socket.close();
                                System.exit(0);
                            } 
                            bw.newLine();
                            bw.flush();
                        } 
                    }
                    catch (NullPointerException ignored)
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    catch ( Exception e )
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();     
                    }  
                    finally
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            socket.close();
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException ignored)
                        {
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }  
                }           
            };
            Server.start();
        }
}
```

Code of `MessengerWithFiles.java`

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class MessengerWithFiles
{
    static boolean contains = false;
    public static int k = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        MessengerClient client1 = new MessengerClient(args);
        MessengerServer server1 = new MessengerServer(args);

            if(args.length == 2 && args.length < 3)
            {
                server1.ServerRun(args);
            }
            else if(args.length!=2 && args.length>2) 
            {
                client1.ClientRun(args);
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use ints as booleans. Don't compare booleans to constants. Unclear what you're asking,

Comment: @EJP where do you see ints being used as booleans and where do you see booleans being compared to constants?